# android anoation not able to see the factory path in eclips

Tags: android, annotations

[image]

I'm trying android annotation files eclipses but there is no option for doing the setup

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this:

**Note**: **"-Aclasspath"** and **"-Asourcepath"** options are automatically passed to all your Java 5 processors by Eclipse,

so it is unnecessary to provide those.

**Adding Annotation Processors**
You can add annotation processors to your project under `Java->Compiler->Annotation Processing->Factory Path:`

Processors can be contained in jar files or in `Eclipse plug-ins`. The Factory Path list includes both `Java 5 and Java 6` processors.

The factory path is stored in a file named **".factorypath"** at the `project root`,

similar to the **classpath**

[**ANDROID ANNOTATION FACTORY PATH**](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_apt_getting_started.htm)

[image: Factory-Path]